# Admin account with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'll have a news section on my new website, those news are taken from a MySQL database. But I don't know what I'll do to add a new post without having to edit the SQL table. I was thinking about doing a newpost page that requires a pass that is a variable on the app.js file.
Is it ok to do that? Or should I do a proper user login?

Comment: Could you explain a little more your issue?

Comment: Shure. I'll have some posts on my new site, they are news about the site. And I'll have to create something to create those posts. My question is: is it ok to use a 'master' password that isn't stored on a database, it's just a variable on app.js?

Comment: I guess @CoderSpinoza got it!

Answer (score 2):

For a basic "are you an admin" system like you've described in your comment, a password stored in `app.js` has some caveats to think about:

- Where is `app.js` stored?  You don't want a plaintext password on GitHub*.
- How obvious is it to the end user how authorization is done?  Could an end user try and brute force the system?

A better idea would be a simple implementation of [Passport](http://passportjs.org).  This allows you to store your passwords securely and there's much less chance of an 'oops' password release.

Many Node.js systems use Passport for auth, so it's a good thing to learn.  Authentication like this is *very* difficult to get right the first time, so save yourself the time and effort and use something written by an expert.

*You could store your credentials in a separate, `.gitignore`'d file, but that's a workaround.

Comment: I think passport is too much of a hassle for what he is trying to do.

Comment: When it comes to authentication and security, hassle is worth it.

Comment: I tought about using Passport before, but to use it I would have to create a new table for just one row.  
And app.js is stored on my VPS, it's not open source.  I don't get the second bullet, what do you mean?

Comment: @CoderSpinoza it's a lot better than rolling your own crypto. Do you think OP understands the problems with MD5 hashes? Or what a salt is? Or how many rounds to use in bcrypt? What about vulnerabilities when using a specific algorithm in a slightly incorrect way? Passport is battle tested and I think it's a much better alternative to attempting to implement this sort of thing clueless.

Comment: @CoderSpinoza Of course there is a way to do security without using passport, the point is that it's not trivial and OP can get it wrong for - let's say not understanding the implications of something because he does not understand mathematics - let's say - group theory. It would _seem_ ok to OP but in practice his site will have issues. See - http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement a simple admin login system. Your browser does not know if your browser is an admin's or not right? Whether it be an email or any verification method, you have to make a request to the server and get a token or something, which you will store in your browser's cookie or localStorage.

Comment: Is it ok to use a 'master' password that isn't stored on a database but just a variable on app.js?

Comment: If your intention is to just make admin account without generic user system, it totally works. Database is for a lot of data with a same type.

Comment: Store it it a separate .env file and try to access your password with process.env.PASSWORD instead of hardcoding it in your app.js.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about .env files. How do I setup it?

Comment: @LucasT. No, it is not ok to use a master password that is just a plain text variable in app.js. It's better not to use a password that is stored in plain text at all. Especially since Node (or JS itself) does not provide a way to store `SecureString`s in memory like you would with Java or C# or offer external packages like Ruby and Python yet. An environment variable is a poor idea as well.

Comment: So using Passport is the only(secure)way? I'll really have to create a new table for just one row, or is there something I can do?

Comment: @LucasT. using passport is not the only way - the alternative is to educate yourself about cryptography in general and the specific algorithms which we use - it's not trivial and it'll take time but eventually you'll have a deeper sense of satisfaction and will be a better professional in my opinion. You can also use another auth system that abstracts it for you.

Comment: Yeap I agree @BenjaminGruenbaum. No plain text at all. probably he can store well-encrypted password in environment variables but that is not a trivial job.

Comment: At moment I don't have the time to learn it(it will probably take a while), so for me creating a new table is the only way, right?